# Koltin flows - Exception handling for individual tasks

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Recently while exploring Kotlin Flows I tried implementing a functionality where I want to run 10 tasks as a part of Flows.
One thing that I am not able to figure out, is how to handle exceptions and retry for individual tasks.

Here's a sample pseudo code of the same.

```
listOfOperations.asFlow().map {
    // Do request here (this would throw exception for some operations
}.collect {
    // Do something with output
}
```

Now the thing I am looking towards is how to add retry mechanism for one of the operations that might fail. And not the entire flow to be restarted.

I saw `retryWhen` can be used. But that ended up restarting the whole flow.

Comment: What exactly is `listOfOperations` here?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `listOfOperations` is some list of input data... why not create "subflows", use `retry` and then flatten the resulting flows?

```
listOf("a", "b").asFlow().map { data ->
    flow {
        emit(someOperation(data)
    }.retry(3)
}.flattenConcat()
```